# Live file system error using EasyBCD

Tags: boot

Error message: (initramfs) Unable to fund a medium containing a live file system

I know this question is a common one, but I used EasyBCD to boot from the iso and it all worked up to a certain point but when it gets to this final stage it shows this error.

The main problem is that now there are no other OSs on my system, so no way to get anywhere and rectify the issue.

Is there anything which can be done aside from burning a Linux iso to a DVD or USB? I don't have either of these things and my DVD drive is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that nothing else will work. Without an OS the options are non-existent, making the task impossible. In the end I bought a flash drive and got Ubuntu up and running that way without a hitch.